# Identity matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have to create a function in Matlab that given a parameter N, it returns the N-by-N identity matrix. I cannot use loops, nor built-in functions like `eye` or `diag`. I have tried the following:

```
function I = identity( n )
    I = zeros( n,n );
    p = [1:n;1:n]';
    I( p ) = 1;
end
```

But, when I call it with `I = identity(3);` I obtain the following result:

```
I =

 1     0     0
 1     0     0
 1     0     0
```

And I don't understand why, because I thought Matlab could use a vector as a matrix index, and the way I did it, I have that:

```
p =

 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
```

So when I do `I( p ) = 1`, the first step should be `I( 1,1 ) = 1` then `I( 2,2 ) = 1` and so on. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using no functions, just [`matrix indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) -

```
A(N,N) = 0;
A((N+1)*(0:N-1)+1) = 1
```

Thus, the function becomes -

```
function A = identity( N )
A(N,N) = 0;
A((N+1)*(0:N-1)+1) = 1;
end
```

Comment: I see we had a similar idea :) +1

Comment: @Benoit_11 Yeah, that's how it ended up!

Answer (score 3):

The way in which MATLAB indexes is column-major, therefore it fills matrix `I` with linear indices contained in `p`, starting at (1,1) then going to (2,1) and so on. Therefore it "sees" the indices as [1 2 3] and then again [1 2 3].

What you could do is change `p` into a 1xn vector containing the appropriate linear indices.

For instance:

```
p = 1:n+1:n^2
```

gives rise to those indices:

```
p =

     1     5     9
```

and the following matrix `I`:

```
I =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

yay!

Comment: I didn't get the `n*(n+1)` part. Obviously the last element will always be `n^2`. Wouldn't `n^2` be enough? nevertheless +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Is [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) allowed?

```
function I = identity(n)

I = bsxfun(@eq,1:n,(1:n).');

end
```

Comment: No, no built-in function is allowed, but thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Going with thewaywewalk's answer, we can achieve the same thing with the `bsxfun` approach but without using any built-in functions... except for `ones`.  Specifically, we can use indexing to replicate rows and columns of vectors, then use the equality operator when finished.  Specifically, we would first generate a row vector and column vector from `1:n`, replicate them so that they're respectively `n x n` matrices, then use equality.  The values in this matrix should only be equal along the diagonal elements and hence the identity is produced.

As such:

```
row = 1:n;
col = row.';
row = row(ones(n,1),:);
col = col(:, ones(n,1));
I = (row == col) + 0;
```

We need to add `0` to the output matrix to convert the matrix to `double` precision as `row == col` would produce a `logical` matrix.  I didn't cast using the `double` function because you said you can't use any built-in functions... but I took the liberty of using `ones`, because in your solution you're using `zeros`, which is technically a built-in function.